# Signing USB dongle using eMudhra token

Tags: c#, cryptography, itext, x509certificate2

I am using eMudhra token for signing a pdf through a windows application.
I am using the CSP provider name "Trust Key CSP V1.0" and am using the below code to read:

```
SecureString varSecureString = new SecureString();
        string password = sPassword;
        char[] secpwd = password.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < secpwd.Length; i++)
        {
            varSecureString.AppendChar(secpwd[i]);
        }

        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Trust Key CSP V1.0", "Trust Key CSP V1.0", strUSBProviderName, new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(), varSecureString);
        csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        string pubKeyXml = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);
        X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in x509Store.Certificates)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(strCertName) && cert.SerialNumber.Contains(strCertSerialNo))
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(sFile.Substring(0, sFile.Trim().LastIndexOf(".") + 1) + "sig", rsaProvider.SignData(File.ReadAllBytes(sFile), "SHA1"));
            }
        }
        x509Store.Close();
```

Can you kindly suggest me where I am wrong in the code or give me an alternate solution.

Comment: What's it doing wrong?

Comment: 1. I don't see any iText code in your question, so why is this question tagged as an iText question? 2. Are you sure that the private key can be used to sign documents? For instance: is the non-repudiation flag set? Not all private keys are suited to sign documents. Ask your CA to explain how to use his keys to sign PDFs.